# New customer address attributes not saving

Tags: attributes

I've created 2 new customer attributes.  These attributes show in the admin under "Customers > Attributes > Manage Customer Address Attributes".

I've overwritten the registration form (register.phtml) to display form fields matching these attributes.  When I debug through the registration process, I see that `Mage_Customer_Model_Form::getAttributes` does not include my new attributes.

Because of this (I think), my new attributes are not being saved in the database.  What step am I missing to make the registration form save my new attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add the attribute to the form-filter

To save new attributes in an EAV table through a form, you need to set the `used_on_forms` setting, like this in a setup file

```
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(
     'customer', 'agb'
);
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'));
```

There are a lot more forms, like `customer_account_edit`.

**Be careful, this example is from a customer attribute, not customer address!**

A few form codes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT form_code FROM `customer_form_attribute` WHERE 1
```

- adminhtml_checkout
- adminhtml_customer
- adminhtml_customer_address
- checkout_register
- customer_account_create
- customer_account_edit
- customer_address_edit
- customer_register_address

I'm not sure whether I got all, maybe there are some, which are not used but mentioned in the code.

Comment: Is there a list of forms?  I have it registered in several, but apparently not the right ones.

Comment: I edited the answer. I don't think there is a list.

Comment: AHA!  I registered the attribute to use the customer_register form, but not the customer_register_address form!

Comment: I cross my fingers, that this worked. I hoped, this might be the problem.